# How to set images or icon to button in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to make the use of small image or icon as on button like below image 
How can i do that?

[image: Click here for image]

Comment: What are you using? WPF, Winforms or ASP.NET?

Comment: I would try something like making a custom control from picture box that cuts off the image before the edge of the button and puts the text in the missing space, or just adds a label right below. Or just use a combo of buttons with an image and a label below it. IF you show what you tried and tell us what didn't work we will be better able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
private void SetMyButtonIcon()
{
    // Assign an image to the button.
    button1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Graphics\\My.ico");
    // Align the image and text on the button.
    button1.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;    
    button1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
}
```

you can use the **other button attributes** like

`Overlay:` image and text share the same space on a control.

`ImageBeforeText:` the image is displayed horizontally before the text of a control.

`TextBeforeImage:` the text is displayed horizontally before the image of a control.

`ImageAboveText:` the image is displayed vertically above the text of a control.

`TextAboveImage:` the text is displayed vertically above the image of a control.

Comment: This code works but image or icon does not set properly brother.as i shown on images